# redirect product-category to a custom page

Tags: customization, pages, woocommerce-offtopic

I hope you can help me.
I've made one page for each woocommerce category I have in my store with a specific design.
The problem is that when you click on the link of the product-category to which a product belongs, it sends you to the custom woocommerce page.
Would it be possible to change this?
I'm using permalink.

http://example.com/product_category/my_product_category/ redirects to
http://example.com/my_product_category/

Thanks